# IIS rewrite subfolder URL to subdomain content

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, subdomain, subdirectory

I'm trying to load content hosted on a subdomain site as a subfolder on the same main domain - I've attempted a variety of IIS URL rewrites with no luck so far. The goal is for a user to go to:

```
domain.com/subdomain1
```

which displays

```
subdomain1.domain.com
```

but keeps the URL as

```
domain.com/subdomain1
```

There are multiple subdomains which I need to do this with.

I have the URL Rewrite module installed and have tried all many of rules.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite changes the path on the server only, if you want the URL to change you need a redirect. You can change this on the rule.